# Create a M3U Playlist With MP3 Music Files

Tags: audio, mp3, music, playlists

I would like to create an m3u playlist for my website which will be at domain/music/Playlist.m3u (example). I need to put the mp3 files in the directory domain/music/ in the playlist so that it will play them. I can't figure out what to put in the playlist file. I tried

```
http://domain/music/1.mp3
http://domain/music/2.mp3
```

but it won't play. Can someone please help me get this working? Thanks!

Comment: Do the mp3 files play in your browser?

Comment: @Papa Yes all of the music files play perfectly fine. No program seems to be capable of actually playing the entire playlist however. This other program I talked about only "plays" it because it just gets the first entry and plays that instead...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
You might want to specify how you are connecting.

Example:`http://www.example.com/music/Mine.mp3`

Example 2:`http://example.com:8000/Mine.mp3`

*Add the www. or the port.*

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that, however it seems that it doesn't work in a browser or Windows Media Player or other programs, but it works in some Java program I found...

Comment: @Josh Please update when you figure it out! Maybe the program does not have the correct credentials to access the files?

Comment: There is no credentials required to access any files or the playlist so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: What's the name of the Java program that it works on?